# Determine which object's tile is taken over

Tags: c#

I'm in the making of a small recreation of the game "Virus". I am making the game for two players but plan to make an option for more players.

If you do a move, you copy your tile to a tile next to you and taking over all surrounding enemy tiles. I currently have it as the following (commented, since everything is in dutch):

```
//Go through the list of direct neighbors of the destination tile
//if that neighbor's team is not neutral and not of their own team, take that tile over
//taking over that tile is currently as follows:

for(int i = 0; i < destinationTile.DirectNeighbors.Count(); i++)
{
    destinationTile.DirectNeighbors[i].Backcolor = players[currentPlayer].teamColor;
    players[currentPlayer].tilesOwned.Add(DirectNeighbors[i]);

    players[currentEnemy].tilesOwned.Remove(DirectNeighbors[i]);
} //tilesOwned being a List on every Player
```

This works for what I currently have: a game with only 2 players. But if I want to play with more than 2 players, this doesn't work. I have to retrieve what enemy the tile has been taken over from.

How do I determine what player's tile has been taken over?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having to add to a player's list and removing from another's is redundant because the same data is represented twice and this might result in inconsistency.

Only keep a unique list of tiles and every tile can have a owner property (nobody or a player id). Then you can get a count by color/player.

With this system instead to add a tile to player's list and removing from another's, you will just change the tile owner property to currentPlayer

Comment: That is actually quite smart. Than I just have to work with a Foreach loop instead of doing what I am doing right now (if im sure, but I will figure it out :p). It's too late to work atm, so I will test it out tomorrow.

Comment: Glad to help. If you get all player counts at once, that works well. Else consider using Linq. You can Filter tiles by some player and then Aggregate to get the count. You can also Filter tiles to get a list of adjacent tiles by imposing absolute value of euclidean distance to be greater than zero and less than 2 (1 or sqrt(2), floored to 1, are accepted).

Comment: Coming back on the foreach loop: I gave every tile an owner element of type Player (either 'null', player1 or player2) and I want to  add score accordingly. Since you can't quite say `foreach(Player owner in Tiles /*2d array of all tiles*/)` because of the type difference, how is this possible?

Comment: @ItsSander just give every Player a Player.id and make the Tile.ownerId match that id. Then just match Tile.ownerId with player.id

Comment: sorry for this, but I don't see how this avoids the issue of the type difference. I have to check the entire array or list, which are tiles. I got around it using 3 for loops and an if statement to get the score (for loops for: looping through list of players, 2 for loops for looping through the 2d array and the if statement to check if the current Tile's owner is equal to the corrent player.). This works since I don't have the restricting element. I am curious to your way now :p

Comment: Ok basically use Linq.  `List<Tile>.Filter(tile=>tile.id==currentPlayer.id).ToList()` this returns only tiles owner by a current player. If you want to `.Aggregate` (to get the count), do it before the final `.ToList()`. In this case the list Count is enough anyway

Comment: I get how it works now. I'll have to update my visual studio's .NET framework for it (still using 2015). But thank you :)